# Ratio of the sides of triangles

Tags: triangles

I am currently reading about the ratios of the sides of triangles.

By basic proportionality theorem, I was able to prove that if DE || BC in a given triangle ABC, then:
AD/DB = AE/EC

And by triangles similarity, I was able to prove that if DE || BC in a given triangle ABC, then:
AD/AB = AE/AC

But I am still confused. I was told by someone(I don't remember who told me) that if DE || BC in a given triangle ABC, then:
AD/DB=DE/BC.

But there is really no way, I can think that this is true. I tried very hard to prove this but I failed. As a last try, I want to know is this really true or am I just wasting time proving this.

Comment: What are $E , D$?

Comment: You are correct.  What you were told by someone is false.

Comment: The Integrator, D and E are just points on the sides AB and AC.

Comment: @GEdgar Does this mean that this answer here is also wrong:https://brainly.in/question/3090283

Comment: Well, saying $D$ and $E$ are points on sides $AB$ and $AC$, respectively, makes a difference.  Then the assertion is true, since $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADE$ are similar triangles.

Comment: @GEdgar But how can I prove that AD/DB=DE/BC? I know about similarity and I have used similarity to prove AD/AB = AE/AC.

Comment: No, not $AD/DB=DE/BC$ but $AD/AB=DE/BC$

Comment: @GEdgar But how should I prove it?